# Python Encryption - Reproducing Error: Data must be padded to 16 byte boundary in CBC mode

Tags: python, encryption, pycryptodome

I'm having trouble reproducing the following error;

```
Data must be padded to 16 byte boundary in CBC mode
```

When I encrypt my data I use the following padding;

```
BS = 16
pad = lambda s: s + (BS - len(s) % BS) * chr(BS - len(s) % BS)
```

and the encryption is done with the following code;

```
encrypt = base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(pad(raw).encode('utf8'))).decode()
```

I have had no issues with the padding or encryption for a good period of time now, but I received this error recently (only once), but I'm not sure how to reproduce it. Can the actual data being passed be the issue? What would trigger this error with 16 byte padding in place?

Comment: What are you trying to do here `chr(BS - len(s)`? If the len of s is greater than 16, the result is a negative number.

Comment: You don't pad the characters anyway, you pad the bytes. In other words, you pad **after** you encode.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk - I mut be blind today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Padding must be performed on the *bytes* to be encrypted, not the characters. With utf-8 encoding, some characters are encoded to multiple bytes. For example, consider the two strings

```py
s1 = chr(0x30)
s2 = chr(0x80)
```

Both strings have length 1, but the length of `s1.encode('utf-8')` will be 1 while the length of `s2.encode('utf-8')` will be 2. Your algorithm will pad `s2` incorrectly.

Here is a modified `pad` function that is not so cryptic. You can turn it into a one-liner if you want.

```py
def pad(s: bytes):
    block_size = 16
    size_of_last_block = len(s) % block_size
    padding_amount = block_size - size_of_last_block
    pad_bytes = bytes([padding_amount] * padding_amount)
    return s + pad_bytes
```

Note, however, that PyCryptodome already includes `pad()` and `unpad()` functions that should normally be used in preference to something home-grown. Example:

```py
import base64
import secrets

from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
from Cryptodome.Util.Padding import pad, unpad


def example():
    key = secrets.token_bytes(32)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC)  # pycryptodome will generate the random IV
    pt = 'Hello World, the secret to success is: Python'.encode('utf-8')
    padded_pt = pad(pt, cipher.block_size, style='pkcs7')
    ct = cipher.encrypt(padded_pt)
    result = base64.b64encode(cipher.iv + ct).decode('utf-8')
    return result, key

def decrypt(key: bytes, encrypted_blob_b64: str):
    encrypted_blob = base64.b64decode(encrypted_blob_b64)
    iv, ct = encrypted_blob[:AES.block_size], encrypted_blob[AES.block_size:]
    cipher = AES.new(key, mode=AES.MODE_CBC, iv=iv)
    padded_pt = cipher.decrypt(ct)
    pt = unpad(padded_pt, cipher.block_size, style='pkcs7')
    return pt.decode('utf8')

result, key = example()
print(f'len = {len(result)}, result = {result}')
print(decrypt(key, result))
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I was able to reproduce the error using characters that encode to multiple bytes, such as €. I took your advice and padded after encoding, but I got a type error; ```TypeError: can't concat str to bytes``` in my pad; ```pad = lambda s: s + (BS - len(s) % BS) * chr(BS - len(s) % BS)``` . Can you shed some light on why this is happening?